# How to get/set values in a private struct in c++?

Tags: c++, struct

I'm having a little problem setting values in my private struct of my Class. It is like the following:

```
//ProcessImage.h

class Process_Image
{
     private:
       struct ImageData
       {
         Mat imageMatrix;
         int V_Min;
         int V_Max;

         Imagedata(Mat img, int Vmin=0, int Vmax=255):
               imageMatrix(img), V_Min(Vmin), V_Max(Vmax) {}
      };

    public:
      bool set_V_Min(int Value);
};


//ProcessImage.cpp

bool Process_Image::set_V_Min(int Value)
{
     if(value>0&&value<256)
     {
     ImageData.V_Min=value; //it is not working setting it like this
     return true;
     }
 return false;

}
```

Where am I wrong? I think it should be possible to set the value in my struct that way but I don't know what I'm missing. Please give me a hint or a direction how to do it the right Way.

Comment: `ImageData` is a type. And you do not hold any instances of it in your class.

Comment: `ImageData` is a private *type*, not an object. You need an instance of it. Would you expect `ProcessImage.set_V_Min(42)` to work, too?

Comment: Damnit you're right.... I could hit myself for missing that little basic thing. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: you can edit the article , left right version to others

Comment: It was my first question here. Should I edit it or post the correct version as "Answer Your Question"?

Comment: No need to edit in the answer. But next time please do add the error message. Usually we can just copy-paste that into the answer :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't created the structure yet, only described it. To have constant structure inside class write it down like this:

```
class Process_Image
{
     private:
       struct ImageData
       {
         Mat imageMatrix;
         int V_Min;
         int V_Max;

         Imagedata(Mat img, int Vmin=0, int Vmax=255):
               imageMatrix(img), V_Min(Vmin), V_Max(Vmax) {}
       }ImageData; // <- your missing part

    public:
      bool set_V_Min(int Value);
};
```